# Problems understanding a statement about the generators of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_7)$ and $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

Well, I'm having some problem understanding a statement of a book (I won't provide a screenshot being this book not in English) that state: $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_7)$ is generated $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

In which sense generated? (I suppose multiplicatively, but I'll love to have a confirmation).

It's also true the same thing for $SL_2(\mathbb{F_p})$ for each prime $p$ ?

How to prove all this?

If you have the patient to write an answer I'll be very happy, but even a reference is enough.

Comment: I'll just answer the easy part: yes generated is meant multiplicatively. Addition makes no sense in $SL_2$ because it is easy to add two elements and land outside the group (that is: get an answer with determinant other than 1).

Answer (score 1):

I will post a **HINT** as an answer that might help you to find on your own the right way to prove it. There is a proof of the above explicitly written in **Lang's - Algebra** (check the *3rd* edition, *chapter XIII*, Lemma 8.1) (at least I read that there for a first time). Think that the above matrices when acting on $SL_2(\mathbb{F})$, no matter field you have, they are acting as elementary row-column operations. Hence the problem can be reduced into finding the solutions of some equations, when you want to split up an element of  $SL_2(\mathbb{F})$ in terms of your generating set. For any queries if you don't have the book (or cannot find it) please do let me know.

Comment: I don't know which part of this group you want to study, but as something to mull over. There is a very beautiful representation-theoritic description of that group, especially when the field has positive characteristic $p>0$. Details can be found in **Alperin's**, *Local representation theory*.

Answer (score 0):

$SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

and the groups you are asking about are images of this group. This classical result has a number of proofs: my preference is to let $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ act on the Farey tree and study stabilizers.

Comment: I think you forgot an 1 in the second matrix.

Comment: Of course! thanks.

Comment: I'm not finding any proof of the fact that those matrix generate SL(2,Z). Everyone affirm it without proving it. Do you have a source to point me at?

Comment: There's a nice explanation in Office Hours with a Geometric Group Theorist, though I don't know if that's the easiest book to get a hold of, since it's brand new. This approach is an instance of Bass-Serre theory, so you could check out Trees. You also have a reasonable chance of proving this by hand via some basic linear algebra. I think LU decomposition basically proves it?